# How to iterate object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this object. I want to iterate this object in JavaScript. How is this possible?

```
var dictionary = {
    "data": [
        {"id":"0","name":"ABC"},
        {"id":"1","name":"DEF"}
    ],
    "images": [
        {"id":"0","name":"PQR"},
        {"id":"1","name":"xyz"}
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can do it with the below code. You first get the data array using dictionary.data and assign it to the data variable. After that you can iterate it using a normal for loop. Each row will be a row object in the array.

```
var data = dictionary.data;

for (var i in data)
{
     var id = data[i].id;
     var name = data[i].name;
}
```

You can follow similar approach to iterate the image array.

Comment: You should put your curly braces on the same line in JS (I normally advocate curly braces on the same line, but JavaScript is weird: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/)

Comment: i have the same array structure but  why does it return undefined

Comment: for...in is not suitable for arrays.

Comment: @TanyavonDegurechaff try removing the `dictionary.data` and just iterate over `dictionary`

Comment: `for...in` is for iterating over object properties. For arrays, use `for...of` instead.

Answer (score 30):

There's this way too (new to EcmaScript5):

```
dictionary.data.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.name + ' ' + item.id);
});
```

Same approach for images

Answer (score 8):

Something like that:

```
var dictionary = {"data":[{"id":"0","name":"ABC"},{"id":"1", "name":"DEF"}], "images": [{"id":"0","name":"PQR"},{"id":"1","name":"xyz"}]};

for (item in dictionary) {
  for (subItem in dictionary[item]) {
     console.log(dictionary[item][subItem].id);
     console.log(dictionary[item][subItem].name);
  }
}
```

Comment: for...in is not suitable for arrays. - so for..in dictionary, but for (var j=0;j<dictionary[i].length;j++)...

Answer (score 4):

Use dot notation and/or bracket notation to access object properties and [`for` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to iterate arrays:

```
var d, i;

for (i = 0; i < dictionary.data.length; i++) {
  d = dictionary.data[i];
  alert(d.id + ' ' + d.name);
}
```

You can also iterate arrays using [`for`..`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops; however, properties added to `Array.prototype` may show through, and you may not necessarily get array elements in their correct order, or even in any consistent order.

Answer (score 3):

Using a generator function you could iterate over deep key-values.

```js
function * deepEntries(obj) { 
    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (typeof value !== 'object') 
            yield [key, value]
        else 
            for(let entries of deepEntries(value))
                yield [key, ...entries]
    }
}

const dictionary = {
    "data": [
        {"id":"0","name":"ABC"},
        {"id":"1","name":"DEF"}
    ],
    "images": [
        {"id":"0","name":"PQR"},
        {"id":"1","name":"xyz"}
    ]
}

for(let entries of deepEntries(dictionary)) {
    const key = entries.slice(0, -1).join('.')
    const value = entries[entries.length-1]
    console.log(key, value)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(index in dictionary) {
 for(var index in dictionary[]){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dictionary = {
        "data":[{"id":"0","name":"ABC"}, {"id":"1","name":"DEF"}],
        "images": [ {"id":"0","name":"PQR"},"id":"1","name":"xyz"}]
};


for (var key in dictionary) {
    var getKey = dictionary[key];
    getKey.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log(item.name + ' ' + item.id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using for and foreach loop

```
var dictionary = {
     data: [{ id: "0", name: "ABC" }, { id: "1", name: "DEF" }],
     images: [{ id: "0", name: "PQR" }, { id: "1", name: "xyz" }]
};
dictionary.data.forEach(item => {
     console.log(item.id + " " + item.name);
});

for (var i = 0; i < dictionary.data.length; i++) {
     console.log(dictionary.data[i].id + " " + dictionary.data[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the options you have:

### 1. [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (ES2015)

```js
var dictionary = {
    "data": [
        {"id":"0","name":"ABC"},
        {"id":"1","name":"DEF"}
    ],
    "images": [
        {"id":"0","name":"PQR"},
        {"id":"1","name":"xyz"}
    ]
};

for (const entry of dictionary.data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(entry))
}
```

### 2. [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (ES5)

```js
var dictionary = {
    "data": [
        {"id":"0","name":"ABC"},
        {"id":"1","name":"DEF"}
    ],
    "images": [
        {"id":"0","name":"PQR"},
        {"id":"1","name":"xyz"}
    ]
};

dictionary.data.forEach(function(entry) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(entry))
})
```

### 3. [`for()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) (ES1)

```js
var dictionary = {
    "data": [
        {"id":"0","name":"ABC"},
        {"id":"1","name":"DEF"}
    ],
    "images": [
        {"id":"0","name":"PQR"},
        {"id":"1","name":"xyz"}
    ]
};

for (let i = 0; i < dictionary.data.length; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(dictionary.data[i]))
}
```