# How to iterate over json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, iteration

Yes there are many post regarding this.But my doubt is little different.I have following array for example

```
var dictionary = {
    "12Jan2013": [{
        "id": "0",
        "name": "ABC"
    }, {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "DEF"
    }],
    "13Jan2013": [{
        "id": "0",
        "name": "PQR"
    }, {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "xyz"
    }]
};
```

Same post is there on same site **BUT here in dictionary `json` array key is dynamic**.Here it is date ie 12Jan2013.It can be any date.It is not static.I have searched for that but didn't get solution.

**How to iterate over such a json array?**

**AND How to print json array as in same formate shown above?**

**EDIT**

Here is my real code.And **i shown a comment in following code** where i wanted to `iterate` data ie `jsonData` var in `getWeatherDataForCities` callback

```
var arrAllrecords = [];
var arrCityrecordForADay = [];
function getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray, callback){

var toDaysTimestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) - (24*60*60);
for(var i in cityArray){

    for(var j=1; j<=1; j++){
        var jsonurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q="+cityArray[i]+"&dt="+toDaysTimestamp;

        $.ajax({
            url: jsonurl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            mimeType: "textPlain",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data){                    
                var arrCityRecordForDay = [];
                /*arrCityrecordForADay.push(data.list[0].city.name);
                arrCityrecordForADay.push(data.list[0].weather[0].description);
                arrCityrecordForADay.push(timeConverter(data.list[0].dt));
                arrCityrecordForADay.push(data.list[0].main.temp);
                arrCityrecordForADay.push(data.list[0].main.humidity);
                arrCityrecordForADay.push(data.list[0].main.pressure)
                arrCityrecordForADay.push(data.list[0].wind.speed);*/
                //'{"pets":[{"name":"jack"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"joe"}]}';

                arrCityRecordForDay.push(
                    {"cityName" : data.list[0].city.name},
                    {"weather" : data.list[0].weather[0].description}
                );

                var tempId = data.list[0].city.name+"-"+timeConverter(data.list[0].dt);

                arrCityrecordForADay.push(
                    {tempId : arrCityRecordForDay}
                );

                if(((arrCityrecordForADay.length)) === cityArray.length) {
                    callback(arrCityrecordForADay);
                }

        } });
        toDaysTimestamp = toDaysTimestamp - (24*60*60);
    }   
}       
}

$(document ).ready(function() {

 var cityArray = new Array();
  cityArray[0] = "pune";

  getWeatherDataForCities(cityArray, function(jsonData) {
        // Here I want to iterate jsonData
  });


});
```

Comment: That's not a JSON array, that's a JS array object. They are not the same. JSON is a data serialization format.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496508/how-to-iterate-json-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I is not duplicate.There is constant keys like data here there is dynamic.I am confused between wheather that is json or just array as Benjamin said above

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use for-in...something like:

```
for (var i in dictionary) {
    dictionary[i].forEach(function(elem, index) {
        console.log(elem, index);
    });
}
```

where the `i` would iterate through your `dictionary` object, and then you can use `forEach` for every json array in the dictionary(using `dictionary[i]`)

With this code you'll get

```
Object {id: "0", name: "ABC"} 0 
Object {id: "1", name: "DEF"} 1 
Object {id: "0", name: "PQR"} 0 
Object {id: "1", name: "xyz"} 1
```

You can tailor the forEach function definition(replacing the `console.log` bit) to do whatever you want with it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/Cz5tu/2/)

Edit: Doing the same thing using `Object.keys`

```
Object.keys(dictionary).forEach(function(key) {
    dictionary[key].forEach(function(elem, index) {
        console.log(elem, index);
    });
});
```

Edit2: Given the somewhat complicated structure of your `jsonData` object, you could try using a (sort of) all-purpose function that would act on each type of component separately. I've probably missed a few cases, but maybe something like:

```
function strung(arg) {
    var ret = '';
    if (arg instanceof Array) {
        arg.forEach(function(elem, index) {
            ret += strung(elem) + ',';
        });
    } else if (arg instanceof Object) {
        Object.keys(arg).forEach(function(key) {
            ret += key + ': /' + strung(arg[key]) + '/';
        });
    } else if (typeof arg === "string" || typeof arg === "number") {
        ret = arg;
    }
    return ret;
}

document.body.innerHTML = strung(jsonData);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/TTuFS/4/)

Comment: If you're using `forEach` you might as well use `Object.keys` and have pretty code all the way :)

Comment: Also note that you will also want to use `hasOwnProperty(i)` to filter out properties that may have been inherited.

Comment: @RyanRansford Just wondering, how would that be relevant in this case?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm not as comfortable with `Object.keys` as I'd like to be...I've added an edit to my answer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar Let me make a fiddle

Comment: @tewathia It will be gr8 for me to understand.And let me update question what i actually did to create that(not same value) array.

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar I've added the fiddle link to my answer. Have a look

Comment: @tewathia your answer is perfect.but i have made some mistack in my code posted in edited answer thats why it is not showing out put.Will you please tell whats going wrong.

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar At a glance, your code looks okay to me(I'm assuming `timeConverter` is defined elsewhere). Let me add though, you can't use my answer directly with your `jsonData` object, because its structure is slightly different. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/TTuFS/)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Doesn't the instantiated object inherit some properties from Object, or is `{}` treated slightly differently than `new Object()`?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that yours is just a JavaScript array object. To make it simple to understand, you can iterate over it like this:

```
for (var i in dictionary) {
    // do something with i
    // here i will contain the dates

    for (n = 0; n < dictionary[i].length; n++) {
        // do something with the inner array of your objects    
        // dictionary[i][n].id contains the "id" of nth object in the object i
        // dictionary[i][n].name contains the "name" of nth object in the object i
    }
}
```

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/Ke8F5/**

The iteration looks like this:

```
12Jan2013 : (id = 0, name = ABC) (id = 1, name = DEF)  
13Jan2013 : (id = 0, name = PQR) (id = 1, name = XYZ)
```

Comment: Thank you.I have edited my question where i have created a dynamic json array.Is it the right way or what i have did is correct?

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar: It all depends on how `data` is structured in your ajax call. Nevertheless, the concept remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop.

```
for (var i in json) {
 ...
}
```

Then, `i` is the current key, so, you can acess json[ i ] and get the data to the corresponding index.

And then, if you need to iterate over inner elements, you can do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for ... in` but you should combine it with `hasOwnProperty` or you'll find yourself iterating over inherited properties likely breaking your code.

```
  for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // Do stuff.
    }
  }
```