# How to transform JSON data in webpage and put the data to specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am new to front-end, I have been looking for hints/relevant solutions in the past few weeks but still no luck. I hope I can solve it out here...I am currently building my first website. I am making a "find recipes" website, since I don't know anything about API call, I created a local Json file which has a few recipes data. The format looks like this:

```
[
  {
        "name": "Fresh Pumpkin Puree (for Pumpkin Pie Filling)",
        "description": "Homemade pumpkin purée. Roasting and draining is the secret to a perfect pumpkin pie filling that will reach canned pumpkin consistency. Use sugar pumpkins(~8 inches, 25 cm in diameter) instead of big pumpkins.",
        "tag": [
            "Puree",
            "Dessert"
        ],
        "ingredient": [
            {
                "amount": "3",
                "unit": "pounds",
                "name": "pumpkin"
            }
        ],
        "step": [
            {
                "description": "Preheat your oven to 375℉ (190℃) F. Cut each sugar pumpkin in half and scoop out the pulp and seeds. We use a grapefruit spoon which seems to help clean out the pulp but a soup spoon works just fine."
            },
            {
                "description": "Line a rimmed baking sheet with parchment paper. Place pumpkin halves cut side down on the paper and roast for 45 minutes until soft and easily pierced with knife, fork or skewer.",
                "img": "stepimg/pumpkin2.jpg"
            },
            {
                "description": "Carefully flip the pumpkin halves cut side up and return to the oven and roast for another 30 minutes.",
                "img": "stepimg/pumpkin3.jpg"
            },
            {
                "description": "Remove from the oven and cool for about 5 minutes. Scoop out the flesh from the skins into the bowl of a food processer. Process until very smooth, several minutes."
            },
            {
                "description": "Transfer the pumpkin purée to a fine-mesh strainer or colander lined with cheesecloth and set over a bowl. Drain for at least one hour.",
                "img": "stepimg/pumpkin5.jpg"
            },
            {
                "description": "Add the wine. Tip: pour the wine into the tomato paste jar and shake it to get the last of the paste out."
            },
            {
                "description": "Add canned tomatoes, cumin, caraway seeds, bay leaves, paprika, erythritol, concentrated stock, and pepper. Yes, that is a lot of cumin; it will be fine. Bring to low boil, reduce heat, simmer for 20 min"
            },
            {
                "description": "Place de-stemmed Swiss chard leaves on top of cooked tomato mixture. Make 8 small depressions with a spoon"
            },
            {
                "description": "Crack one egg into each depression. Cover (a transparent lid is ideal)"
            },
            {
                "description": "Cook until egg white is _just_ set. Serve immediately, in the pan."
            }
        ],
        "notes": "The resulting purée should stand up on its own only slightly slumping when piled high. If the puree is too thick (unlikely), you can thin it with some of the drained liquid. If it's too runny allow it to drain further.",
        "source": "[Fresh Pumpkin Puree (for Pumpkin Pie Filling)](https://recipeland.com/recipe/v/fresh-pumpkin-puree-for-pumpkin-57531)",
        "image": "https://recipeland.com/images/r/22001/e5e9854cbfecece089f6_550.jpg"
    },
]
```

I made the static interface for result page and cooking step page with html&css already

```
            <div class="colm">
            <img src="image/leftdish.jpg">
            <h5 class="dishNameh5">Dish Name</h5>
            <ul class="ingSummary">
                 <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">nature</i>
                    <span class="ingContent">beef, spanish, salt, oil, soy sauce, beef, spanish, salt, oil, soy sauce</span>
                 </li>
                <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">timelapse</i>
                    <span class="ingContent">30 minutes</span>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="colm">
            <img src="image/middish.jpg">
            <h5 class="dishNameh5">Dish Name</h5>
            <ul class="ingSummary">
                <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">nature</i>
                    <span class="ingContent">beef, spanish, salt, oil, soy sauce, beef, spanish, salt, oil, soy sauce</span>
                </li>
                <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">timelapse</i>
                    <span class="ingContent">30 minutes</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="colm">
            <img src="image/rdish.jpg">
            <h5 class="dishNameh5">Dish Name</h5>
            <ul class="ingSummary">
                <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">nature</i>
                    <span class="ingContent">beef, spanish, salt, oil, soy sauce, beef, spanish, salt, oil, soy sauce</span>
                </li>
                <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">timelapse</i>
                    <span class="ingContent">30 minutes</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

 <section id="ingOverview">
    <div class="ov3070container">
        <div class="ovLeft">
        </div>
        <div class=ovRight>
            <h3>DISH NAME</h3>
            <div class="ovRight-left">
                    <ul class="SingleIngSummary">                                
                            <h4>Main Ingredients</h4>
                            <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">nature</i>
                            <span class="dishName">Salmon, green onion</span>
                            </li>
                            <h4>Secondery Ingredients</h4>
                            <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">nature</i>
                                <span class="dishName">Salt, oil, soy sauce, or any seasoning of you choice</span>
                            </li>
                    </ul>                    
            </div>
            <div class="ovRight-right">
                    <ul class="SingleIngSummary">
                            <h4>Difficulity</h4>
                            <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">bubble_chart</i>
                            <img src="image/rating.png" height="22px" width="126px">
                            <span class="smText">Elemantary</span>
                            </li>
                            <h4>Cooking Time</h4>
                            <li class="w3-large"><i class="material-icons w3-large">timelapse</i>
                            <img src="image/rating.png" height="22px" width="126px">   
                            <span class="smText">10 Minutes</span>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
            </div> 
        </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="divideLine"></div>
<section id="cookingSteps">
    <div class="Container1008">
        <p><span class="bgText">1.</span>&nbsp Preheat grill on high heat. After grill is heated, clean grate with grill brush. Reduce heat to medium high heat.</p>
        <img src="image/rawsalmon.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="divideLine2"></div>

        <p><span class="bgText">2.</span>&nbsp Generously oil the grill grate by squirting some vegetable oil on a paper towel and using grill tongs, rub the oil on the grill grate.</p>
        <img src="image/onion.jpg" alt="img">
        <div class="divideLine2"></div>

        <p><span class="bgText">3.</span>&nbsp Season salmon fillets with salt and pepper. Place salmon diagonally on the grill grate. Grill salmon for 3-4 minutes per inch of thickness on each side with the lid closed.</p>
        <img src="image/grilled_salmon.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>  
</section>
```

[Here is a screenshot of the result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cUwD.png)

[Screenshot of the cooking step page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alOPT.png)

I wonder how can I insert the data in my Json file to the DIVs I have in my html file? So the the actual "name", "ingredients", "step" etc. from the JSON will show up correctly?

Thank you for helping

Comment: can you show the `ajax` call that produces the `JSON`?  either way, I would suggest using `id` on your spans and mapping incoming `JSON` object to them accordingly.  some naming conventions may allow you to iterate it programmatically but, even brute force should suffice.

Comment: Are you using (or planning on using) any templating engines or front-end frameworks? Or are you doing this all in vanilla javascript, html & css?

Comment: For do that you have to iterate your JSON object and create the html structure in javascript

Comment: @Curt he lists jQuery

Comment: @JorgeMejia you can map the object's properties instead of iterating through it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example for do what you want.

You have your JSON object, then you have to map the JSON and create your html structure for append to the template container.

```js
var data = [
 {
   name : "Fred",
   last : "Durst"
 },
 {
   name : "Jonathan",
   last : "Davis"
 },
 {
   name : "Corey",
   last : "Taylor"
 }

]

var htmlStructure="";

data.forEach(function(element){
    htmlStructure +=    "<li>"+ element.name + ' ' + element.last + "</li>"
});

$('#container').append(htmlStructure)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="container">
  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: hmmm. I put 
$.getJSON("recipes.json", function() {
   //how can I loop through the JSON?

    });   
the js file and json file are separate.

Comment: Ok, you just have to recive the object in your function $.getJSON("recipes.json", function( jsonData ) { // Here you can loop through jsonData   });

Comment: the console gave me fail to load error message: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
r.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
getJSON @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ main.js:4
j @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
fire @ jquery.min.js:2
i @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.js:2
S @ jquery.min.js:3


Answer (score 1):

What you'd have to do is write some JavaScript to iterate over the JSON object and then set the HTML/text of the respective HTML element.

So if you had an array like:

```
{name: "Pizza",ingredients:["tomatoes","cheese","dough"]}
```

Your JS would have to:

1. Loop through the JSON
2. Iterate over each object and grab the value(s)
3. Insert the text into its respective HTML div

[How to append data to div using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)

[How to iterate JSON array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496508/how-to-iterate-json-array-in-javascript)

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

Comment: How to loop through the JSON? the js file and json file are separate.

Comment: Is it local or on another web server?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create new HTML using the data in the JSON:

Take a chunk of the current HTML, copy it and remove all of the data. Then you can append a template literal with the new data to the page.

```
let recipe = {description: 'Super cool recipe'};
let newHTML = `<div>${recipe.description}</div>`;
```

After that you just need to find where in the page you want to stick it, and put it there. You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML), or if you're using jQuery you can use `$(someElement).after(newHTML)`

Answer (score 0):

alright assuming your incoming `JSON` comes from something like:

```
.done(function( data ) {} ... , "json");
```

you can then label your spans (to be filled) like:

```
<span id="dishSpanID" class="ingContent">beef, spanish, ... , soy sauce</span>
```

then you can insert into those spans something like:

```
  .done(function( data ) {
    $("#dishSpanID").html(data[0].name);
  }
```

this is only an example and you need to do it for each element on the page.